# Can't figure out why javascript isn't storing my variable

Tags: javascript, html, variables, onclick

I'm trying to figure out why my javascript function isn't storing my JS variable.

Here's the issue. I trigger my storeMacAddress function with an onclick event, and the alert shows that the 'userMac' variable gets the form value properly. I need to be able to use this value later on, so I need the value stored in a variable that my other functions can user.

However, when I call my testVariable function, the console says that the 'usermac' variable is not defined.

Here's the javascript:

```
function storeMacAddress()
{
    var userMac = document.getElementById("MacAddress").value
    alert("testing: " + userMac);
    return userMac;
}

function testVariable(MacAddress)
{
    alert(MacAddress);
}
```

Here's the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src='./index.js'>
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1></h1>
<p></p>
<div>
    <form id="userRequest">
    Mac Address: <input type="text" id="MacAddress"><br>
    <input type="submit"
    onclick="storeMacAddress();"
    value="Save Mac Address">

    </form>
</div>


<button onclick="
testVariable(userMac);
">Test</button>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `userMac` is defined in the scope of the function `storeMacAddress`, therefor `testVariable` has no access and cannot pass in that parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are defining the variable inside the function, it is not visible outside the function or even to other functions, hence we can define it outside where it will be accessible to all the functions, you can just assign values inside the function or access it inside the function!

- **Note: I have changed `type attribute` of `input` to text, so that the
  variable assignment is visible in the snippet!**

```js
var userMac;

function storeMacAddress() {
  userMac = document.getElementById("MacAddress").value
  if (userMac)
    alert("testing: " + userMac);
  return userMac;
}

function testVariable(MacAddress) {
  if (MacAddress)
    alert(MacAddress);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src='./index.js'>
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <h1></h1>
  <p></p>
  <div>
    <form id="userRequest">
      Mac Address: <input type="text" id="MacAddress"><br>
      <input type="button" onclick="storeMacAddress();" value="Save Mac Address">

    </form>
  </div>


  <button onclick="
testVariable(userMac);
">Test</button>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I see now what I was doing wrong, your code helped very much. thanks

Comment: @TomD You're welcome! read more about javascript variables [here](http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-variable-scope-and-hoisting-explained/)

Answer (score 1):

1. You are creating the variable within the scope of the function, and not within a closure. Learn about closure.
2. You are wiring the function inline, which means that your return is completely useless. Look up the concept of “unobtrusive JavaScript”. Keep your JS and HTML separate, if you don't use a view-binding layer, like JSX, and even if you did, keep your services and your view logic separate.
3. You are using a submit, inside of a form. Even if this did what you wanted, the page would immediately be reloaded, and you would lose everything. Look up form actions.
4. To submit to the server, your form field should have a `name`.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'll look into this.